# MSBuild property evaluated multiple times

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

This worked before updating to Visual Studio 15.8.4:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TempFolder>$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())$([System.Guid]::NewGuid())</TempFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<UsingTask TaskName="RTL_CSS_Compiler.Build.NodeInstaller" AssemblyFile="$(TempFolder)\BuildTasks.dll" />

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_TargetItems Include="$(SolutionDir)\BuildTasks\bin\$(Configuration)\*.*">
      <InProject>false</InProject>
    </_TargetItems>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="$(TempFolder)" Importance="high" />

  <!-- Copy BuildTasks and its dependencies and execute them from a temp directory to avoid
  MSBuild error due to Visual Studio node reuse locking the output assemblies.
  https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/msbuild-custom-task-and-assembly-locks/ -->

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(_TargetItems)" DestinationFolder="$(TempFolder)%(RecursiveDir)" />
  <NodeInstaller />
</Target>
```

It correctly copied the built BuildTasks and its dependencies to a temporary directory, then executed it from there. Now MSBuild returns with the error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\fb69480f-28f1-49be-882e-a6d4beb68f7e\BuildTasks.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

While the output of the `Message` command is:

> C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\62fe9a44-6fcd-4b78-9de6-98a4d8247dd4

The binaries are correctly copied to the directory stated by the `Message`.

Why is the value of `TempFolder` different when used in `UsingTask` than when it used in `Copy` and `Message`? It seems like the expression in the property is evaluated multiple times. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue on the Visual Studio 2017 15.8.1 and 15.8.4. Both of them got the same value. So, I think this issue should be more related to your project/solution. Have you tried to clean the build, restart VS or PC? If all above not help, could you please reproduce it with a new sample project then share it to us, so we could check it directly.

Comment: I tried all the above. I'll try to reproduce it in a new project and come back to you.

Comment: So it turned out, that we didn't need the build task after all, so I'm not going to spend more time on troubleshooting it (I wasted way more on it than I should anyway). If anyone has the same problem though, and is able to fix it, I would be interested to know what the solution was.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it's getting evaluated multiple times.
As a work-around you could save off the value of the GUID into it's own property like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <myguid>$([System.Guid]::NewGuid())</myguid>
  <TempFolder>$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())$(myguid)</TempFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Nope :( . I still get different value in `AfterBuild` than in `UseTask`. I also tried to print it in `BeforeBuild` and it prints the same as in `AfterBuild`. Can you reproduce this? Probably a VS2017 15.8.X issue, as it worked before the upgrade.

Comment: I tried reproducing it, and it works fine for me. I'm using `Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.168+ga8fba1ebd7 for .NET Framework`

Comment: I tried this and it all worked:  <PropertyGroup>
  <myguid>$([System.Guid]::NewGuid())</myguid>
  <TempFolder>$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())$(myguid)</TempFolder>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <Target Name="AA">
  <Message Text="GUID AA $(myguid)" />
  <Message Text="Temp Path $(TempFolder)" />
 </Target>
 <Target Name="BB" DependsOnTargets="AA" >
  <Message Text="GUID BB $(myguid)" />
  <Message Text="Temp Path $(TempFolder)" />
 </Target>

Comment: If I were you I'd just not use that NewGuid function then. Since you are creating the folder you should clean it up when you are done. Therefore just use a name you choose yourself: <myguid>ScoobiesRevenge</myguild>

Comment: I'm using this process as a workaround for MSBuild locking the assembly of the build task. See: https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/msbuild-custom-task-and-assembly-locks/ and so I need the automatically generated name. If you have a better solution to this, I would gladly use it, but I haven't found any other workaround.

Comment: I've read that blog post on word-press and now have to ask: Why would you want to remove that node installer assembly during the build at all? I have been doing builds for years, and never needed to do that. If you respond, we should do it in a private chat, This is getting too long here. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was also surprised that this basic task cannot be done without problems. Anyways, it turned out we didn't need the build task after all, so it's not that important anymore. Nevertheless, thanks for your help.